# Getting Title Bar on specific Activity when Theme.NoTitleBar is applied to application

Tags: android, themes, android-manifest, titlebar

Suppose I have an android app with `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` applied to the application element in the manifest.

Is it possible, for a specific activity, to deviate from this application-wide theme and *declaratively* (i.e. through the manifest) get a title bar for that activity?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to define new theme for that particular activity? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#theme ?

Comment: That could be one approach, I guess - to avoid cruft, I just hoped to be able to get back the titlebar without referring to any specific themes, just as the reverse, removing the titlebar, can be achieved this way.

Comment: Ah, I see. Maybe you can use [FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE) (I did not try it myself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non-declarative solution proposed by @arun-c-thomas put me on the right path:

Applying `@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault` reverts the no-titlebar theme. It is not ideal in that it applies a full theme that would also revert other customizations that might have been in place, but in my case this is not an issue.

Comment: As a note, the specific style item that controls the titlebar is android:windowNoTitle

Answer (score 1):

Use  `setTheme(..)` before calling `setContentView(...)`and `super.oncreate()` of your specific *Activity*

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //set Theme here
        setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                .....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was specifically after a declarative solution though. I also see it as problematic that to reverse the titlebar off, I would have to know specifically which overall theme is in effect; i.e. in your solution, referring to DeviceDefault_*Light*. You reply put me on the right path, however, and it seems applying android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" to the activity declaration achieves what I'm after.